# How do I make a trigger accumulate data every time it is updated in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a 'roomstate' table that represents states that I keep updated.

```
CREATE TABLE ROOMSTATE
(
    `RoomState_ID`          INT       NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT ,  
    `Room_ID`          INT       NOT NULL    ,
    `RoomState_State`  BOOL      NULL       , 
    `Cust_ID`          INT       NULL   ,
    `Booking_ID`       INT       NULL   ,
    CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (Roomstate_ID)
);
```

This table is updated when an employee assigns a room to a customer and shows the status of the rooms.

```
INSERT INTO ROOMSTATE(Room_ID, RoomState_State, Cust_ID, Booking_ID) 
 (select room_id, '0', null, null from room);



select * from roomstate;

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Roomstate_ID  ROOM_ID  ROOMSTATE_STATE  CUST_ID  BOOKING_ID
     1           1           0           NULL        NULL
     2           2           0           NULL        NULL
     3           3           0           NULL        NULL
     4           4           0           NULL        NULL
     5           5           0           NULL        NULL      
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is what happens when the employee assigns room 2 to customer 1 whose booking_id is 2.

```
select @custid = 2;
select @Bookingid := (select booking_id from booking where cust_id = @custid),
@RoomAloct := 1;

UPDATE roomstate
SET booking_id = @Bookingid
where roomstate.room_id = @RoomAloct;

UPDATE roomstate
INNER JOIN booking ON roomstate.booking_id = booking.booking_id
SET roomstate.cust_id=booking.cust_id;

UPDATE roomstate
SET roomstate_state = 1
where roomstate.cust_id IS NOT NULL ;

select * from roomstate;

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Roomstate_ID  ROOM_ID  ROOMSTATE_STATE  CUST_ID  BOOKING_ID
     1           1           1             2          2
     2           2           0           NULL        NULL
     3           3           0           NULL        NULL
     4           4           0           NULL        NULL
     5           5           0           NULL        NULL      
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

As the table above is continuously updated, the existing contents may become NULL again.

I'd like to have a record of updating this in another table.

example :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PK_LOGTB  ROOM_ID  ROOMSTATE_STATE  CUST_ID  BOOKING_ID  DATETIME
     1           1           1             2        2      2021-06-06 00:00:00(NOW)
     2           2           1             5        3      2021-06-06 00:00:00(NOW)
     3           3           1             8        4      2021-06-06 00:00:00(NOW)
     4           1           0             2        2      2021-06-07 00:00:00(NOW)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get this log table? I guess I have to write a trigger.

Comment: Learning about triggers is too broad for a question on Stack Overflow.  If you are attempting to write one and have a specific question, then ask that as a question.

Comment: For what it's worth, the MariaDB fork of MySql offers [system-versioned](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) tables. These capture the history of INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs automatically. This would be a great way to meet your requirement without a mess of triggers and extra tables. But you'd still have to figure it out.